# How to Re-Create Missing Vim Directory?

Tags: 11.10, vim

The `/etc/vim` directory and the symlinks from `/usr/share/vim` to it are missing. Does anyone know how to re-create the directory and links?

I've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge vim
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Did you delete them, or did they just disappear somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You need to force apt-get to reinstall the package files, since a regular 'install' command will take shortcuts.  You may also need to reinstall some of the other vim-related packages.  Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim vim-common
```